# Solutions for $a^x+b^y=2^z$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all solutions for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge2}$ s.t. 
$$a^x+b^y=2^z$$ where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge2}$

Because of Beal's conjecture, for $x,y,z\ge3$ implies $a$ and $b$ should be even. Does there exist any other solution except $2^x+2^x=2^{x+1}$?

Comment: For any solution you have $v_2(a)=v_2(b)$ and hence to find all solution it suffices to find all solutions with $a$ and $b$ both odd. All other solutions are obtained by multiplying them by appropriate powers of $2$, as illustrated in John Omielans answer. Of course you can also reduce to the case where $x$ and $y$ are both prime.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$ such that

$$a^x+b^y=2^z \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

where $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 2}$, there are solutions other than $2^x + 2^x = 2^{x+1}$. For example, there is

$$13^2 + 7^3 = 169 + 343 = 512 = 2^9 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You can use this equation to derive an infinite # of other related solutions. Multiply both sides by $2^{6n}$, for any positive integer $n$, to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(13^2)(2^{6n}) + (7^3)(2^{6n}) & = (2^9)(2^{6n}) \\
\left(13(2^{3n})\right)^2 + \left(7(2^{2n})\right)^3 & = 2^{6n+9}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: Thanks, Is there any method to find all the solutions?

Comment: @Pruthviraj You're welcome. Note I just added how you can get an infinite number of counter-examples from my one. As for any method to find all solutions, I don't know of any, but I am quite certain there are more. Due to the Beal conjecture & the limits of Pythagorean triples, I suspect all such counter-examples would have one of the terms on the left being squared. This then becomes an elliptic curve equation, for which I believe relatively little is known about the integral solutions to it. However, this is not an area I'm particularly expert in, so I can't really say much more about this.