# Triplets of the form $a^p+b^q=2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This a follow up (generalization) to the query asked here: [Triplets of the form $a^2+b^2=2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3549913/triplets-of-the-form-a2b2-2n)

**Query:** Are there infinitely many triplets $(a,b,n)$ such that:
$a^p+b^q=2^n$

where:

- $a$ and $b$ are odd positive integers
- $p$ and $q$ are greater than 2

**Comment:** We already know that no solutions exist (from the earlier query) when both $p$, $q$ are even integers.

Comment: Your title says $2n$ but the body says $2^n$. Which is it?

Comment: You may want to read up on the [$abc$ conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture)

Comment: Related to the (open) Beal conjecture

Comment: Thank you to you both. So I guess its reasonable to assume I won't get a solution here ;) Thanks again..

Comment: @TheoryQuest1 FYI, if you allow one of $p$ or $q$ to be $2$, there is at least one solution, with it given at [Solutions for $a^x+b^y=2^z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3544460/602049), but I suspect there are many more, possibly infinitely many.